# Is there a custom service factory on ServiceStack, something analogous to custom controller factory of ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: servicestack, aop, factory

I wanted to have a control on service creation so I can make necessary adjustments to make the service's method calls interceptable. The interception will be made possible via postweaving of LinFu to service's DLL

We can do DI on ServiceStack, but it won't DRY the code; think logging service calls if made via DI, every service will need to expose a DI interface for an ILogger. AOP can remove the need to put a DI-injected interface, AOP is the best code DRYer

Is there a custom service factory on ServiceStack? so DRYing code is possible

This made me want to implement AOP on my service: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23333/Introducing-LinFu-Part-VI-LinFu-AOP-Pervasive-Meth

Answer (score 2):

Implement an IContainerAdapter (and optionally IRelease) for your DI container and then wire it in AppHost.Configure. E.g. for Windsor you do:

```
    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        ...
        var compositionRoot = new WindsorCompositionRoot(WindsorContainer);
        container.Adapter = compositionRoot; 
        container.CheckAdapterFirst = true;
        ...
    }
```